# How to ensure that all the runnables get fired concurrently, using a ScheduledExecutorService in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm trying to implement a Java program that prepares a bunch of runnables for databases(there are hundreds of them, and I want to allocate a thread for each database), and run each of those runnables using a `ScheduledExecutorService`, with an initial delay and some delay in between executions. This is what I've managed so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Get db name and info as key-value pairs
        Map<String, DbInfo> dbInfoMap = getDbInfoMap();;
        
        // Initialize the scheduled executor service.
        final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors
                .newScheduledThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());


        // For each database, get a list of runnable and process accordingly.
        dbInfoMap.forEach((db, dbInfo) -> {
            // Get a list of runnable(s).
            List<Runnable> runnableList = new MigrationTaskManager(db, dbInfo).getRunnableTasksForDB();
            // Schedule all the runnable(s) using the scheduled executor service, and a delay
            runnableList.forEach(runnable -> executorService
                    .scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, INITIAL_DELAY, DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        });
    }
}
```

This sort of does what I intend, albeit with some caveats (It takes a really long time to start processing some databases if the list is too long). How can I implement it so that all the runnables for each database get fired at the same time? For instance, If I have 100 databases to read from, how can I ensure that 100 threads get fired with a bunch of runnables in each thread when the program starts? I'd really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Looks like you really only have one task per database and these tasks then execute each individual step. Scheduling the individual steps only makes sense if they are truly independent and should be scheduled as such.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I'm basically performing the same set of tasks for multiple databases (hundreds of them), and looking for a way to do that concurrently.

Comment: `newScheduledThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())` doesn’t allocate a thread for each database, it allocates a thread for each CPU. To have a thread per database, you’d need `newScheduledThreadPool(dbInfoMap.size())`, but the optimal number of threads is more likely something between those values.

Comment: @RoshanUpreti: but in your question you say "want to allocate **a thread** for each database". So if you have (for example) 10 databases and 100 tasks each, how many threads do you want to run concurrently? It *sounds* to me that you want (at most) 10, yet your code tries to schedule 1000 tasks).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I want to allocate a thread for each database and use that thread to execute the runnable. So, if there are 10 databases, there should be 10 threads and each thread running its list of runnable. My apologies if I phrased the question incorrectly.

Comment: Then you shouldn't schedule each element of the `runnableList` individually. Instead construct a `Runnable` that simply loops over them and calls each of them (normally, serially) and schedule that.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thank you for pointing me towards the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

For maximum efficiency, pass a collection of your hundreds of tasks to an executor service assigning one virtual thread per task.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor();
executorService.invokeAll ( collectionOfTasks )
```

### Scheduling of a thread’s execution is out of your control

Your title says:

> ensure that all the runnables get fired concurrently

If you mean that you want all of the `Runnable` tasks to execute simultaneously, that is not possible using Java threads.

#### Platform threads

In Java, you ask for a thread to be executed, but when execution begins, and how long execution lasts, is up to the whims of the host OS’ thread scheduler. Threads in today’s Java are each mapped to a host OS thread. ([Virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) in upcoming Java 21+ will be quite different than these “platform” threads.) A Java programmer has no control over when a thread runs.

You *can* collect a bunch of tasks to be submitted together to an executor service. Pass the collection of tasks `ExecutorService#invokeAll`. But `invokeAll` does *not* mean they will be executed together. They can be executed in any order, with each task’s execution beginning at any time, and completing at any time. The `invokeAll` method is merely a convenience for you the programmer if you have chosen to instantiate all your tasks up front. You could just as well write a loop that submits each instantiated task object to the executor service, one task at a time.

Here is an example app to demonstrate passing a collection of `Callable` objects to the `invokeAll` method of an `ExecutorService`.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ManyDatabases
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        ManyDatabases app = new ManyDatabases ( );
        app.demo ( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println ( "INFO - Demo done. " + Instant.now ( ) );
        // Dummy data
        List < DatabaseInfo > databaseInfos =
                IntStream
                        .rangeClosed ( 1 , 1_000 )
                        .mapToObj ( ( int index ) ->
                                new DatabaseInfo (
                                        ENGINE.values ( )[ ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( ENGINE.values ( ).length ) ] ,
                                        index
                                )
                        )
                        .toList ( );
        System.out.println ( "databaseInfos = " + databaseInfos );

        // Make tasks.
        List < DbTask > tasks = databaseInfos.stream ( ).map ( DbTask :: new ).toList ( );

        // Execute tasks.
        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor();
        )
        {
            try
            {
                List < Future < Boolean > > futures = executorService.invokeAll ( tasks );
            }
            catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
        }
        System.out.println ( "INFO - Demo done. " + Instant.now ( ) );
    }
}

enum ENGINE { POSTGRES, MS_SQL_SERVER, MYSQL }

record DatabaseInfo( ENGINE engine , int address ) { }

class DbTask implements Callable < Boolean >
{
    final private DatabaseInfo databaseInfo;

    public DbTask ( final DatabaseInfo databaseInfo )
    {
        this.databaseInfo = databaseInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call ( )
    {
        System.out.println ( Instant.now ( ) + " TASK Simulating update to database: " + this.databaseInfo );
        try { Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofMillis ( ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 400 , 800 ) ) ); /* Simulate real work being done. */ } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
        return true;
    }
}
```

When run.

```
INFO - Demo done. 2023-09-01T01:54:11.199225Z
databaseInfos = [DatabaseInfo[engine=MS_SQL_SERVER, address=1], DatabaseInfo[engine=POSTGRES, address=2], DatabaseInfo[engine=POSTGRES, address=3], DatabaseInfo[engine=POSTGRES, address=4], DatabaseInfo[engine=POSTGRES, address=5], DatabaseInfo[engine=MYSQL, address=6], DatabaseInfo[engine=MYSQL, address=7]]
2023-09-01T01:54:11.229579Z TASK Simulating update to database: DatabaseInfo[engine=POSTGRES, address=5]
2023-09-01T01:54:11.229285Z TASK Simulating update to database: DatabaseInfo[engine=POSTGRES, address=2]
2023-09-01T01:54:11.229423Z TASK Simulating update to database: DatabaseInfo[engine=POSTGRES, address=4]
2023-09-01T01:54:11.229342Z TASK Simulating update to database: DatabaseInfo[engine=POSTGRES, address=3]
2023-09-01T01:54:11.229840Z TASK Simulating update to database: DatabaseInfo[engine=MYSQL, address=7]
2023-09-01T01:54:11.229797Z TASK Simulating update to database: DatabaseInfo[engine=MYSQL, address=6]
2023-09-01T01:54:11.229291Z TASK Simulating update to database: DatabaseInfo[engine=MS_SQL_SERVER, address=1]
INFO - Demo done. 2023-09-01T01:54:12.051448Z
```

### Virtual threads

In Java 21+, we have [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444), an alternative to platform threads. The scheduling of virtual threads is managed within the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) rather than by the host OS. When the JVM detects a virtual thread is blocking, the virtual thread is dismounted from the “real” platform thread where it executes. The virtual thread is parked while waiting for the blocking to resolve. In the meantime, the JVM mounts another virtual thread onto the platform thread. This means vastly greater utilization of your CPU cores as the host OS threads rarely sit idle.

Database calls always involve much [blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_%28computing%29), taking a long time while waiting for a response. You are making hundreds of such calls at a time. So this is ideal situation for switching to virtual threads rather than platform threads.

Switching to virtual threads is utterly simple: just swap out the `Executors` call.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor();
```

And we can increase our example calls to a thousand, or even a million. Virtual threads are vastly lightweight than platform threads. Millions of concurrent virtual threads is reasonable.

```
.rangeClosed ( 1 , 1_000 )
```

And let's not dump the entire `databaseInfos` list of a thousand. Just first and last, now easier to do as `List` implements `SequencedCollection` with convenient `getFirst` & `getLast` methods. See [*JEP 431: Sequenced Collections*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

```
System.out.println ( "databaseInfos = " + databaseInfos.getFirst () + " … " + databaseInfos.getLast () );
```

When run:

```
INFO - Demo done. 2023-09-01T02:03:50.729476Z
databaseInfos = DatabaseInfo[engine=MYSQL, address=1] … DatabaseInfo[engine=POSTGRES, address=1000]
2023-09-01T02:03:50.781280Z TASK Simulating update to database: DatabaseInfo[engine=MS_SQL_SERVER, address=3]
2023-09-01T02:03:50.781686Z TASK Simulating update to database: DatabaseInfo[engine=MYSQL, address=8]
2023-09-01T02:03:50.781739Z TASK Simulating update to database: DatabaseInfo[engine=POSTGRES, address=7]
…
2023-09-01T02:03:50.807384Z TASK Simulating update to database: DatabaseInfo[engine=POSTGRES, address=1000]
2023-09-01T02:03:50.807377Z TASK Simulating update to database: DatabaseInfo[engine=MYSQL, address=997]
2023-09-01T02:03:50.806946Z TASK Simulating update to database: DatabaseInfo[engine=MS_SQL_SERVER, address=951]
INFO - Demo done. 2023-09-01T02:03:51.638269Z
```